# Add text and background color to div from html form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add both text color and background color to a hidden div from a form. Once either text or background input fields have been populated, the div should appear with the pre-populated text in the new color and background too. The code is as below:

**For the CSS**

```
.testcolor{
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:hidden; 
}
```

**For the HTML**

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" id="txtcolor" class="tstcolor" name="txtcolor" value="#FF0000">
    <input type="text" id="bgcolor" class="tstcolor" name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
    <a href="#" class="preview">Preview</a>
    <div class="testcolor">
        Lorem ipsum ist nuch nach in die postimen obscurites nang interust ingrostech hochester gelumen bransiolen.
    </div>
</form>
```

**For the Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tstcolor").keyup(function(){
        var txtcolor = $("#txtcolor").val();
        var background = $("#bgcolor").val();

        $("#txtcolor").css("color",txtcolor);
        $("#bgcolor").css("background-color",background);

        $('.preview').click(function(){
            $("#testcolor").css("visibility","visible");                        
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of pasting all the code - use the JSFiddle for giving a live example - It would be easy for us to review as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tstcolor").keyup(function(){
        var txtcolor = $("#txtcolor").val();
        var background = $("#bgcolor").val();

        $("#txtcolor").css("color",txtcolor);
        $("#bgcolor").css("background-color",background);
        });

        $('.preview').click(function(){ // Place onclick outside keyup event
            var txtcolor = $("#txtcolor").val();
            var background = $("#bgcolor").val();
            $(".testcolor").css({"background-color":background,"color":txtcolor}).show();//use class selector,i.e (.) for class and (#) for id                       
        });

});​
```

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqzk7/3/)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted. One more question, how do I make the div to appear without clicking on the preview button, i.e, i would like it to appear and show changes after keyup on either of the input fileds. What about clicking on the div to close it?

Comment: Thank you Sibu. Worked like a charm:)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
            $("#testcolor").css("visibility","visible");                        
});
```

to

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
   $(".testcolor").css("visibility","visible");                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use text instead of val

```
var txtcolor = $("#txtcolor").text;
var background = $("#bgcolor").text;
```

and

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
 $(".testcolor").css("visibility","visible");                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were mentioning `#testcolor` instead of `.testcolor` and you were assigning the css properties to the TextBoxes not the `div`. Change the css properties inside click event as  you want to show the changes when you click on the `a` tag. (If you change the css outside the click event, then the div will change whenever there is a change in the values of the TextBoxes)

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ohuciv/3/edit)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".tstcolor").keyup(function(){
      var txtcolor = $("#txtcolor").val();
      var background = $("#bgcolor").val();            
      //removed div css properties from here
      $('.preview').click(function(){
         //added div css properties
         $(".testcolor").css("color",txtcolor);               
         $(".testcolor").css("background-color",background);
         //replaced '#' with '.'
         $(".testcolor").css("visibility","visible");              
      });
   });
});
```

Check this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ohuciv/3/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".tstcolor").keyup(function() {

    var txtcolor = $("#txtcolor").val();
    var background = $("#bgcolor").val();
    $("#txtcolor").css("color", txtcolor);
    $("#bgcolor").css("background-color", background);
});

$('.preview').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(".testcolor").show().css({
        'color': $("#txtcolor").val(),
        'background-color': $("#bgcolor").val()
    });
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/DzKGM/)